# Degeneracy of term-symbols and Pauli exclusion principle in the Russell-Saunders scheme

Tags: angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals, pauli-exclusion-principle, term-symbols

In the Russell-Saunders scheme, let us consider a configuration of $N$ equivalent electrons (i.e., belonging to the same subshell $(n,\ell)$). Let $|L\ S\ M_L\ M_S\rangle$ denote a common eigenstate shared by the operators $(\hat{L}^2,\hat{S}^2,\hat{L}_z.\hat{S}_z)$, where $\hat{L}=\sum_{i}^N \hat{L}_i$ and $\hat{S}=\sum_{i}^N \hat{S}_i$ are the total angular-momentum and spin operators, respectively.

According to my instructor's notes, if an eigenstate $|L\ S\ M_L\ M_S\rangle$ is compatible with the Pauli exclusion principle, then all the states corresponding to the remaining $(2L+1)(2S+1)-1$ pairs $(M_L,M_S)$ are compatible as well, hence it is possible to assign a term-symbol $^{2S+1}L$ to the subspace spanned by the corresponding electron configurations.

What is the proof for such a statement?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "is compatible with the Pauli exclusion principle"?

Comment: Are you familiar with a type of operator known as a "permutation operator"?

Comment: @hft My instructor mentioned it, but didn't provide any formal definition. I thought something in the lines of "Assuming antisymmetric states are eigenstates of the permutation operator, if such an operator commutes with both L^2 and S^2 then they share a common basis". The problem is I lack a rigorous definition of the operator.

Comment: I think you want to make an argument along the following lines... The total $\vec L$ and total $\vec S$ operators are simple sums of the respective single-particle operators (e.g., $\vec L = \vec L_1 +\vec L_2+\ldots+\vec L_N$). Therefore these operators commute with the permutation operator (e.g., $[\vec L, P_{ij}] = 0$ for any $i$ and $j$). Therefore, applying the raising and lowering operators (which is how you generate the rest of the states) can not change the eigenvalue of the permutation operator.